# Сортировка массивов

Tags: массивы, javascript, prompt, сортировка

Здравствуйте.

Сейчас более детально изучаю javascript. Но возник вопрос по массивам, в частности как сделать так, чтобы массив сортировался после заданного пользователем количества ввода параметров (через prompt). В общем, не совсем понял, как представить массив как переменную, которой можно присвоить prompt и затем отсортировать.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что здесь исправить, чтобы пользователь вводил 5 чисел, которые публиковались бы отсортированными по убыванию. Что не так? Спасибо.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    array [i] = Number(prompt ("Введите число"));
    var array = [i];
    array.sort(function(a, b) { return b - a; });
    document.write (array + " ");}
</script>
```

Comment: @Riptor, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Старайтесь не использовать глобальных переменных, если в этом нет необходимости (а она редко бывает). Так же Number не лучший вариант использования, подбробнее тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369220/why-should-you-not-use-number-as-a-constructor

Чтобы использовать массив, его сперва необходимо инициализировать (по понятным причинам вне цикла):

```
var arr = [];
```

Сортировку так же необходимо вынести за цикл (зачем вам сортировать массив при каждом пользовательском вводе?)

```
var arr = [];
for (i=0; i<5; i++) { 
    arr[i] = Number(prompt ("Введите число"));     
}
arr.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return b - a; 
}); 
document.write(arr + " ");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/00dg2sqa/

Comment: Ага-а... Спасибо большое! Очень интересно! Вопрос: зачем поставили круглую скобку и точку с запятой после нее (там же закрыта фигурная скобка уже) после `"return b - a;"`?

Comment: @Riptor, пожалуйста! Фигурная скобка закрывает тело функции обратного вызова, а кргулая - функцию sort